# i can't receive any answer from Watson Discovery

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, chatbot, watson-discovery, watson-assistant

I am working in a chatbot with Watson Assistant and Discovery but I can't  receive any answer from Discovery 
this is the dialog when I used the discovery intent 
[image]

and this is the output from the UI that I designed 
[image]

```
function updateMessage(res, input, response) {
// if (!response.output) {
//     response.output = {};
// } else 
if (response.output.action === 'callDiscovery') {
  // if you want to use natural_language_query, set here the input from the user like my example: 
  params.natural_language_query = response.input.text || null;

    console.log('Calling discovery');
    discovery.query(params, (error, returnDiscovery) => {
        if (error) {
          next(error);
        } else {
          console.log('return from discovery: '+returnDiscovery);
          //if you want to send all text returned from discovery, discomment these lines
            var text;
              for (i = 0; i < returnDiscovery.results.length; i++) {
                text += returnDiscovery.results[i].text + "<br>";
              }
          //sending the TEXT returned from discovery results
          response.output.text = 'Discovery call with success, check the results: <br>' + text; //results */
          //sending the PASSAGES returned from discovery results
          response.output.text = 'Discovery call with success, check the results: <br>' + returnDiscovery.passages[0].passage_text; //passageResults
          return res.json(response);
        };
    });
} else if (response.output && response.output.text) {
    return res.json(response);
}
```

}

Comment: Just change lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()  to lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer. If you put the (), your callable has already been called and thus is not a callable anymore...

Answer (score 2):

tokenizer should be lemmatizer.lemmatize and not lemmatizer

```
 lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
 TFIDF = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=lemmatizer.lemmatize,analyzer= 'word',min_df=3,token_pattern=r'(?u)\b[A-Za-z]+\b',stop_words= 'english')
```

output

```
TFIDF.fit_transform(['how are you', 'facing issue','hope this well help you' ])
#o/p
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: you need do download wordnet  after importing nltk, just run nltk.download('wordnet')

Answer (score 1):

The tokenizer argument in the `TfidfVectorizer` is for overriding the string tokenization step. For e.g. you can use a function as shown below which accepts string as argument, tokenizes the string and return tokenized words.

```
def tokenizerFunc(x):
    return x.split()
```

This function accepts string as input and returns list of words. The reason you get the error "**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" is because function 'WordNetLemmatizer()' does not accept any argument, however when using this function within `TfidfVectorizer` string is passed as an argument for it to be tokenized.

In case you want to lemmatize and tokenze simultaneously you can use this function below

```
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
def tokenizerFunc(x):
    tokenizedList = x.split()
    lemmatizedList = [ lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in tokenizedList] 
    return lemmatizedList
```

you have to use it like this

```
TFIDF = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenizerFunc,analyzer= 'word',min_df=3,token_pattern=r'(?u)\b[A-Za-z]+\b',stop_words= 'english') 
tfidf_matrix = TFIDF.fit_transform(df2['job_title'])
```

Comment: I did it but faced this
tokenizerFunc(df2['job_title'])
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: i want to implement it in a column   df2['job_title']

Comment: modified the answer to show how to use it on column df2['job_title']